# Creating a cross target date series with JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I am attempting to create a method that will return a date series of an arbitrary length that can then be used to generate a usage report grouped by hour/day/month.

It is very important that this can target multiple databases. I have a solution for individual implementations, but it is rather unwieldy.

This is the use case:

```
Table<Record> generateDateSeries(OffsetDateTime minDate, OffsetDateTime maxDate) {
  ## TODO implement 
} 
Table<Record> truncatedDateSeries = generateDates(OffsetDateTime.now().minus(Duration.ofDays(7)), OffsetDateTime.now());

// So that it can then be used in a query such as the following

/*
 * Get all of the usage with a date range grouped by a date part
 */
db.select(
         truncatedDateSeries.field(columnDate).cast(OffsetDateTime.class),
         dataTable.field(columnDownload).cast(BigDecimal.class))
  .from(truncatedDateSeries)
  .leftOuterJoin(dataTable)
  .using(field(columnDate)).fetch()
```

My current implementation of `generateDateSeries` is as follows:

```
Table<Record> generateDates(OffsetDateTime minDate, OffsetDateTime maxDate) {
    Name cte = name("dateSeries");
    Name dateValue = name("dateValue");

    return DSL.withRecursive(cte).as(
      select(value(minDate).as(field(dateValue)))
        .unionAll(
          select(
            field(dateValue, OffsetDateTime.class).add(1)).from(cte).where(
            field(dateValue).add(1).lessThan(maxDate)
          )
        )
    ).select().from(cte).asTable();
  }
```

Eventually when we end up running the query we get

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 188
```

Fair enough.

However, even after looking and playing around with `dateAdd` and `timestampAdd` I have been unable to come to a working solution, let alone a clear and concise one.

Comment: While it is certainly possible to standardise this through jOOQ, I would recommend you use vendor specific extensions for performance reasons. Using recursive CTE is probably not going to give you fast results here, in most RDBMS. Since you seem to be starting with PostgreSQL, I would suggest using `generate_series()` there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to standardise on your interval arithmetic is to use [`DSL.timestampAdd()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#timestampAdd-org.jooq.Field-java.lang.Number-org.jooq.DatePart-), which works with the `TIMESTAMP` data type (i.e. `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`). Support for [`DSL.offsetDateTimeAdd()` is on the roadmap](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6723), and not yet available as of jOOQ 3.11.

Having said so, standardising on `OffsetDateTime` will cause its own difficulties, as various RDBMS have different understanding of what `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` means.